# Почему когда я открыл php файл в браузере?

Tags: php

почему когда я открыл php файл в браузере он открывает так в браузере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код

```html
<?php require_once 'header.php'?>

<section class="modules">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row sec-des">
            <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-6 second-description">
                <p><strong>«Сапи» — это многомодульная система,</strong> где каждый модуль работает на увеличение прибыли, оптимизацию времени, упрощение работы или другие жизненно-важные аспекты работы. Ознакомьтесь с каждым модулем подробнее:</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="module-slider">
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-content">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <p>Не следует, однако забывать, что постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение
                                нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании
                                дальнейших направлений развития. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры позволяет
                                выполнять важные задания по разработке систем массового участия.</p>
                            <p>Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание систем массового участия.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="restourant-hotel">
    <div class="rh-slider">
        <div class="rh-slider-item d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="container align-items-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                        <div class="row"><img src="../image/restaurant.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row flex-column justify-content-start">
                            <p>С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности играет важную роль в
                                формировании соответствующий условий активизации. Задача организации, в особенности же
                                консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации существенных финансовых и
                                административных условий.</p>
                            <p>Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что укрепление и развитие структуры играет важную
                                роль в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что новая
                                модель организационной деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации форм развития.</p>
                            <p>Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и место обучения кадров способствует подготовки
                                и реализации модели развития. Товарищи! постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
                                представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rh-slider-item item-2 d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="container align-items-center">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-1">
                        <div class="row"><img src="../image/hotel.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="row flex-column justify-content-start">
                            <p>С другой стороны дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности играет важную роль в
                                формировании соответствующий условий активизации. Задача организации, в особенности же
                                консультация с широким активом способствует подготовки и реализации существенных финансовых и
                                административных условий.</p>
                            <p>Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что укрепление и развитие структуры играет важную
                                роль в формировании дальнейших направлений развития. Повседневная практика показывает, что новая
                                модель организационной деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации форм развития.</p>
                            <p>Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и место обучения кадров способствует подготовки
                                и реализации модели развития. Товарищи! постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности
                                представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки новых предложений.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="description-features">
    <div class="describtion-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="head-2"><h2>САПИ – ЭТО НОВОЕ СЛОВО В СФЕРЕ РЕСТОРАННОГО БИЗНЕСА</h2></div>
                <div class="head-4"><h4>НОВОЕ СЛОВО С НОВОГО АБЗАЦА, НОВОЙ СТРАНИЦЫ И БОЛЬШОЙ БУКВЫ</h4></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>Кафе и рестораны, наверное, одни из самых сложных в управлении сфер бизнеса.</p>
                    <p>Это настоящая ‘органика’, живой организм, где нужно уделять большое внимание всем нюансам, чтобы бизнес был в зоне положительной рентабельности.</p>
                    <p>Вы, как управленец, не должны тратить все свое время на систематическую работу по анализу работы Ваших официантов, чтобы понять эффективность их работы.</p>
                    <p>Вы не должны постоянно воевать с дизайнерами и арт-директорами по поводу качества проделанной работы.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p>Вы не должны ломать голову в поисках путей поднять планку компетентности своих сотрудников.</p>
                    <p>Эта рутина мешает Вам заниматься процессом развития и гармоничного контроля работы предприятия.</p>
                    <p>САПИ сделает эту работу качественно, в срок, предоставляя полноценную и правдивую информацию о предприятии и Ваших работниках. Это ведь не администратор, чъе мнение зачастую ангажировано не в Вашу сторону.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="features-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row features">
                <div class="head-2 col-md-12"><h2>Основные преимущества системы:</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-spartphone.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Сапи позволяет с легкостью управлять своим рестораном на расстоянии со своего телефона или планшета</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-maids.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Держать весь ваш персонал в тонусе на 180% каждую минуту, заставляя работать только на Вашу прибыль.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-search.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Следит за эффективностью работы Ваших официантов и помогает добиваться их наиболее рентабельной работы.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-arrow.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Анализирует и показывает все слабые места в продажах Вашего предприятия.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-brush.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Становится Вашим Арт-дир
                            ектором и персональным дизайнером.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-book.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Проводит систематическое профессиональное обучение Ваших сотрудников.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-exam.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Помогает выявлять бесполезных сотрудников по средствам тестирования.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-network.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Имеет в команде более 20 лучших специалистов, которые всегда в ожидании оказать Вам помощь по любым вопросам деятельности предприятия.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-between">
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-24hours.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Всегда в работе 24/7. Программный комплекс САПИ работает без перерывов на обед и выходных.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-procents.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Повышай продажи максимально рентабельных позиций из меню.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-price.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Наслаждайся повышением рентабельности уже через 1-ый месяц работы!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature-item col-md-3">
                    <div class="feature-img"><div class="img-contaner"><img src="/image/feature-message.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature-text">
                        <p>Держать весь ваш персонал в тонусе на 180% каждую минуту, заставляя работать только на Вашу прибыль.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="clients-views">
    <div class="our-clients">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="head-2"><h2>наши клиенты</h2></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="clients-slider">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="client-slider-item col-md-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="/image/client-big-papa.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-slider-item col-md-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="/image/client-pishka.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-slider-item col-md-3">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="/image/client-mama-mia.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-slider-item col-md-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="/image/client-guse.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="client-slider-item col-md-2">
                            <div class="row">
                                <img src="/image/client-south-street.png" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-slider">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="views-slider-container col-md-9">
                    <div class="views-slider-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="img-controls col-md-4">
                                <div class="client-slider-image d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <img src="/image/view-slider-client.png" alt="">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="view-text col-md-8">
                                <h2>Максим Владинский</h2>
                                <p>Ресторанный бизнес – для увлеченных! Это Вам не магазин. Я стал ресторатором 8 лет назад, и, как и тогда сейчас болею своей работой 24/7. Сапи – для меня самый эффективный инструмент для помощи в управлении и контроле работы предприятия. Я просто не представляю свою работу на данный период времени без модуля продажи и аналитика. Их использование повернуло мою работу в значительно более прибыльное русло!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="views-slider-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="img-controls col-md-4">
                                <div class="client-slider-image d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <img src="/image/view-slider-client.png" alt="">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="view-text col-md-8">
                                <h2>John Doe</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A accusamus at consectetur consequatur debitis, ducimus illum magnam modi optio, porro quisquam recusandae rem vitae voluptatem voluptatum. Aspernatur cum dicta eligendi exercitationem fuga illum iusto maxime nostrum quo ullam. Beatae dolore earum fugiat magnam maxime officia quam sit totam vel vero! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deleniti, fugit.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="views-slider-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="img-controls col-md-4">
                                <div class="client-slider-image d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <img src="/image/view-slider-client.png" alt="">
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="view-text col-md-8">
                                <h2>Marry Appricot</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad cupiditate expedita laudantium modi nesciunt odit placeat quae quisquam repudiandae? Dolorem fugiat minus natus placeat quod quos sapiente sunt, ullam veritatis voluptates. Eligendi eos eum facere id impedit iusto quidem quis similique voluptatibus. Accusantium atque aut beatae cum dolore dolorem, dolores ducimus ea eligendi, eos excepturi explicabo Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur, cumque?</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<?php require_once 'footer.php'?>
```

Comment: браузер не умеет выполнять php-код, он просто его отображает. php-код может быть выполнен только интерпретатором языка php, который обычно запускают web-сервера при обращении к php-файлу через них

Comment: поищи в интернете курс Дмитрий Валак  Экстремальное создание сайтов на PHP и MySQL , там и установка веб сервера apachе и mySQL и PHP и многое другое полезное найдешь если возникают такие вопросы

Answer (score 1):

Потому что php скрипты выполняются только с установленным и включенным веб-сервером, таким как apache например

Есть готовые пакеты, которые упрощают настройку и установку, например [OsPanel](https://ospanel.io/)